# If u have a sequence of measurable subsets of a finite interval with measure at least $ \delta >0 $ ...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a finite interval  and a sequence of measurable subsets of  that  interval with measure at least  $\delta >0 $ ,prove that there is  at least one number in that interval that belongs to infinitely many of measurable subsets.

I was solving a problem and during the proof, I thought that such claim must be true, but I didn't know how to prove it.

Is it really true? 
How can I prove it?

Comment: Call those sets $E_m$. Try computing the measure of $\bigcap_n \bigcup_{m \geq n} E_m$

Comment: @Shalop oh yes!the set u mentioned is the elements of the interval that appears in infinitely many of measurable subsets and the measure of this set is infinite, so there are infinitely many such elements and not just one!

Comment: The measure of that set is **not** infinite. But you are correct that it is the set of all elements appearing in infinitely many of the $E_n$. Try computing it again.

Comment: @Shalop yes the measure is at least $\delta  $.so there are infinitely many such elements and not just one! Correct?

Comment: Yes, that was my thinking.